# Compare two created from two excel file Dataframe, Create/update new column based on that

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel file, A and B. A is Master copy where updated record of employee Name and Organization Name (`Name` and `Org`) is available. File B contains `Name` and `Org` columns with bit older record and many other columns which we are not interested in.

```
   Name      Org
0   abc    ddc systems
1   sdc    ddc systems
2   csc    ddd systems
3   rdc    kbf org
4   rfc    kbf org
```

I want to perform following operation.!

1) For all existing entries in File B (column `Name` and `Org`), I would like to compare file B with file A, create another two column ('`Newemployee`' and '`Org_change`') in file B .

- update '`Newemployee`' column with '`Y`' if we find missing entry of Name in file B under '`Name`'.
- update '`Org_change`' column with 'New Org name(As per comparison with Sheet A)', if we noticed change in organization under '`Org`'

As of now I have concat both Dataframe to get the new employee name
but not getting further clue how to proceed,

```
full_set = pd.concat([B, A]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'])
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what does it do if you use the keyword `keep` and set it to `False`? `diff_set = pd.concat([old, new]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep=False)`

Comment: @Uvar: Sorry, Just check this comment. !

Answer (score 0):

While dropping duplicates, you can opt for not keeping either of the copies, which basically means you are only keeping the unique values. If one of the DataFrames is a strict subset of the other, this will give you your update.

```
diff_set = pd.concat([old, new]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep=False)
```

It would seem your indices are not matched well. If you run into this problem, it might be required to first set your index.

```
diff_set = pd.concat([old.set_index("Org"), new.set_index("Org")]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep=False).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Where the last `reset_index` is just to revert to the format where the index is just an enumerating counter.

Edit:

```
ll
Out[101]: 
  Name          Org
0  abc  ddc systems
1  sdc  ddc systems
2  csc  ddd systems
3  rdc      kbf org
4  rfc      kbf org

ll2
Out[102]: 
   Name          Org
0   abc  ddc systems
1   sdc  ddc systems
2   csc  ddd systems
3   rdc      kbf org
4   rfc      kbf org
5  Spam  ddc systems
6  John  ddc systems
7   Foo  ddd systems

diff_set = pd.concat([ll.set_index("Org"), ll2.set_index("Org")]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep=False).reset_index(drop=False)

diff_set
Out[104]: 
           Org  Name
0  ddc systems  Spam
1  ddc systems  John
2  ddd systems   Foo
```

I can add any number of employees and it keeps working. ^^

Comment: Before indexing and after indexing I am getting same result. but it's jumbled up. Organization Name is not mapped to employee name .!

Comment: Are you meaning to say that the Organization column is decoupled from the Name column? As in, there is no merit to checking them together?

Comment: not completely, say for 5 employee are working in `ddc systems`, I can see only 2 employee working in  `ddc systems` in out put. I know it's little bit strange.

Comment: interesting..And you do mean to say 5 new employees? This answer is catered to giving you the new updates only.. :/

Comment: yes.. 5 New employees! I am double checking from my side if I am missing any clean up is require on column or any other possibility .!